# How to change font-size in a div after selecting the text only in that div

Tags: jquery, html

I am using the below code to change the font-size of the text in a `<div>`. It changes the font-size, but first you need to select the size in drop-down then click on that text and only then is the font-size affected. However I would like the font-size to be changed immediately for the selected text. Can you help me?

**HTML**

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<form id="myform">
    <select id="fs"> 
        <option value="Arial">Arial</option>
        <option value="Verdana">Verdana</option>
        <option value="Impact">Impact</option>
        <option value="Comic Sans MS">Comic Sans MS</option>
    </select>

    <select id="size">
        <option value="7">7</option>
        <option value="10">10</option>
        <option value="20">20</option>
        <option value="30">30</option>
    </select>
</form>

<br/>

<div id="name" class="name">dsfdsfsfdsdfdsf</div> 
<div id="address" class="address">sdfsdfdsfdsfdsf</div> 
<div id="address1" class="address1">sdfsdfdsfdsfdsf</div>
```

**Script**

```
$(".name").click(function(){
    var id = this.id;
   $("#"+id).css('font-size', $('#size').val()+"px");
});

$(".name").click(function(){
    var id = this.id;//get clicked id
    $("#"+id).css('font-family', $('#fs').val());
});
```

Answer (score 1):

DO this and see..

```
$("#size").change(function() {
    $(".name, .address, .address1").css('font-size', $('#size').val() + "px");
});
```

Answer (score 1):

There's no event able to catch if text is selected, but you can use mousedown/mouseup to simulate it and check for window.getSelection():

```
$(".name, .address, .address1").on("mousedown", function () {    
    $(this).one("mouseup", function () {            
        if (window.getSelection().toString().length > 0)
            $(this).css('font-size', $('#size').val()+"px");
    });
});
```

Check it at [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ZqJJn/3/)

**upd**: thanks for minus. Updated answer

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But it not fulfill my requirement. The font-size should be changed after selection of the text only. i.e, first we have to select text and then select font-size in drop-down then only the font-size of that div should be change.

Answer (score 1):

this work for you

```
$("div").focus(function(){
$(this).css('font-size', $('dropdown').val());
});
```

first you cans select the font size from dropdown then focusing on the div
 jquery get the size from dropdown element and change the divfont as well

Answer (score 0):

From what you have explained in your question, I see your code does what you want. Answer by mohkhan is if you change the size select field automatically the font size of the div will be changed. Is that what you expect?

Also one other correction, you have bind two click events to the same div, you can change the font within the first handler like

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(".name").click(function(){
    var id = this.id;
    $("#"+id).css('font-size', $('#size').val()+"px");
    $("#"+id).css('font-family', $('#fs').val());
    });

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

From your question, i believe you wish to change the text size and font when clicked over it and at the same time you wish to change the size and font once the dropdown value of size or font is altered.

You can try the code below to achieve this.

**jQuery:**

```
var current_id;
$("#fs").change(function(){
    $("#"+current_id).css("font-family",$(this).val());

});

$("#size").change(function(){
    $("#"+current_id).css("font-size",$(this).val()+"px");

});

$(".name,.address,.address1").click(function(){
var id = this.id;
current_id = id;
$("#"+id).css('font-size', $('#size').val()+"px");
});

$(".name,.address,.address1").click(function(){

var id = this.id;//get clicked id
    current_id = id;
   $("#"+id).css('font-family', $('#fs').val());

});
```

**Fiddle:**
http://jsfiddle.net/tamilmani/pKyHL/

Answer (score 0):

So many work, why don't you just make a bbCode? It would be a lot more simple.

Answer (score 0):

This should do what you are asking... It seems like a good solution to me:

http://jsfiddle.net/CLjZt/2/

jQuery:

```
$('div[data-entry=item]').click( function() {
    id = this.id;
    $('#fs').change( function(){
        $("#"+id).css('font-family', $('#fs').val());
    });
    $('#size').change( function(){
        $('#'+id).css('font-size', $('#size').val()+"px");
    });
});
```

HTML:

```
<form id="myform">
    <select id="fs"> 
        <option value="Arial">Arial</option>
        <option value="Verdana">Verdana</option>
        <option value="Impact">Impact</option>
        <option value="Comic Sans MS">Comic Sans MS</option>
    </select>

    <select id="size">
        <option value="7">7</option>
        <option value="10">10</option>
        <option value="20">20</option>
        <option value="30">30</option>
    </select>
</form>

<br/>

<div data-entry="item" id="name" class="name">dsfdsfsfdsdfdsf</div> 
<div data-entry="item" id="address" class="address">sdfsdfdsfdsfdsf</div> 
<div data-entry="item" id="address1" class="address1">sdfsdfdsfdsfdsf</div>
```

The function adds a click event to the selector **div[data-entry=item]** and then records the id of the element that was clicked to the variable **id**. It then fires two functions which listen for a change in the **#fs *and* #size select** elements. If a change is detected it uses the same selector you created to make the change to the css properties to the **value** of the selected **option** element.

*(you could remove this data type and use the same id for all 3 items, but i wasnt sure if you needed both the class and id's on your elements for some reason)*

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
$('.name, .address, .address1').focus(function(){
    var fontSize = $('#size').val() + "px";
    $(this).css('font-size', fontSize);
});
```

If you're wanting to select the text first, and then change the font-size when you select a font in the drop-down (instead of selecting font-size first like I have here), you could create a variable for the selected text and set an event-listener to update whenever the focus is on one of your divs

```
var selectedDiv;
$('.name, .address, .address1').focus(function(){
    selectedDiv = this;
});
```

The just create another event listener to change the font whenever the user selects a font-size.

```
$('#size').change(function(){
    var fontSize = $('#size').val() + "px";
    $(selectedDiv).css('font-size', fontSize);
});
```